# Second Website doesnt show in configuration

Tags: magento-1.8

I have added a second Website (with own store and view) to my Magento 1.8 installation. The first website/shop works great, no problem.

However, If I try to do some basic things as:
* edit this second website/store/view settings from Configuration I cant select this website/store/view. I am only seeing the initial one
* try to add a new page, only for this new website I cant add as the same, I cant select the second website for this.

Any clue ?

Comment: Do you have store and store view for your website ? and store have category root ?

Comment: Yes, I have.
The problem seems to be solved without my intervention, some sort of caching interfered with me "seeing" the second site in admin...